# Скрыть div блок через N сек., после появления

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
success: function(data) { $('#success').html("Повідомлення успішно видалено"); }
```

---

Как можно скрыть данный блок, через 3 секунды после появление? появляетсся надпись по клику.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

```
success: function(data) { 
  const $success = $('#success');
  $success.html("Повідомлення успішно видалено");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $success.hide();
  }, 3000);
}
```

вот так можно

если скрыть уже отображённый, то вызовите с задержкой $('#success').hide()

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант с выполнением анимации

```
success: function(data) { 
  const $success = $('#success');
  $success.html("Повідомлення успішно видалено");
  $success.delay(4000).fadeTo(200, 0).slideUp(200);
}
```

Вариант с удалением уведомления

```
success: function(data) { 
  const $success = $('#success');
  $success.html("Повідомлення успішно видалено");
  $success.delay(4000).fadeTo(200, 0).slideUp(200, () => {
      $success.remove();
  });
}
```

Comment: Значит тогда использовать первый вариант, или создавать элемент заново если он был удален

Comment: Перед так будет работать $success.show().delay(4000).fadeTo(200, 0).slideUp(200);

Comment: Я же написал выше как сделать, перед delay(4000) нужно прописать show()